# Installing Ubuntu 15.10 Server offline

Tags: offline

Is it possible to install Ubuntu Server from the .iso without being online? If so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: You can use the "no network" test case instructions, [here](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/347/builds/105086/testcases/1441/results). But basically, just proceed as normal, and continue whenever it complains about no network.

Comment: The same way you install it while being online; a network connection is not required.